# Error visualizing Mahapps metro style

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget-package, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to use the Mahapps's Metro Style v1.0 stable in VS2013 with Windows 7. According to the initial modification in the  [quick start](http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html) section, the main window should look like this:
[image]
but instead look like this:
[image]

When I used version 0.7 worked fine.
Has anyone else experienced this?

**Interesting fact:**

The second image is what I get, it is saved in .jpeg, but when I saved the screenshot in .png format, it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have always these basic [stuff](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro#a-short-how-to):

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Window xaml**

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                      Title="MainWindow"
                      Height="600"
                      Width="800">
  <Grid>
    <!-- now your content -->

  </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

**Window xaml code behind**

```
using System;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls; // MahApps.Metro reference

namespace WpfApplication
{
  public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said when I added the resources it works fine, but without them, should I get something similar to the first screenshot? By the way nice templates.

Comment: Update: For some reason the `TitleForeground`'s value is Black. When I changed to white I can see the window's title.

Comment: the resources are a must have!!! the quick start guide is step by step walkthrough to get the theme stuff!

Comment: OK. How can I get the initial Black Theme??

Comment: there is no initial Black Theme!!! if you want the MahApps Black Theme add the BaseDark.xaml and not the BaseLight.xaml resource to the App.xaml resources!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can see how everything is implemented on very simple examples to GitHub [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)
Surely you forgot to remove or add what is namespace in xaml page or not remove window parameters.

Comment: I performed step by step as described in the quick start section. As I said with version 0.7 worked fine.

Comment: It's the same one that is in the quick start.I've just double checked. Now when I added the built in styles worked like the tutorial( the one that get the window light blue).